# AngularJS : Calling function in factory from html ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to call a fucntion(myfunc), which is declared in Factory, from html :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="myfunc(search_name)">Search</button>
```

The controller and the factory code are as follows:

```
var angularjsapp = angular.module('graphApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angularjsapp.factory('searchFactory', function() {
      //return $resource('friends.json');
      return{
            myfunc:function(search_name){
                console.log('ok')
                keyword_type = 1
                WebSocketTest(search_name,keyword_type)

                }
            }   
    });

angularjsapp.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope,searchFactory) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.namesPerPage = 10
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.searchFactory = searchFactory.myfunc 
});
```

So far I am unable to log 'ok' in the console

Comment: You could change your html to call searchFactory(search_name) instead of myfunc(search_name) since thats what you have mapped in your js "$scope.searchFactory = searchFactory.myfunc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `scope` function assigned to `searchFactory.myfunc` like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="searchFactory(search_name)">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store reference of `searchFactory` in `$scope.searchFactory` variable

```
$scope.searchFactory = searchFactory;
```

instead of

```
$scope.searchFactory = searchFactory.myfunc;
```

**OR**, Use set variable as `myfunc` in `scope`

```
$scope.myfunc = searchFactory.myfunc;
```

instead of

```
$scope.searchFactory = searchFactory.myfunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$scope.searchFactory = searchFactory.myfunc
```

Do something like:

```
$scope.myfunc = function(arg) {
    searchFactory.myfunc(arg);
}
```

Then, define `search_name` in `ng-click="myfunc(search_name)"` either as a model:

```
<input ng-model="search_name">
```

Or scope:

```
$scope.search_name = "Nicholas";
```